# Applying different functions to generator depending on its length

Tags: python, generator

#### Problem

I have an iterator `spam` to which I want to apply the function `foo` if it generates few items, and `bar` otherwise. With other words, I wish to translate the following code for iterables to generators:

```
if len(spam) <= max_size_for_foo:
    foo(spam)
else:
    bar(spam)
```

`max_size_for_foo` is comparably small so there is no problem if a list or other iterable of this length is created, but if `spam` is long, it must not be converted to a list (otherwise, memory problems ensue).

#### Dissatisfying solution

The best solution I could come up with so far is the following:

```
first_items = []
try:
    for i in range(max_size_for_foo+1):
        first_items.append(next(my_generator))
except StopIteration:
    foo(first_items)
else:
    my_generator = chain(first_items, my_generator)
    bar(my_generator)
```

However, extracting a temporary list and chaining back into the generator feels rather dirty and inelegant to me.

#### Question

Is there a more elegant or Pythonesque way to do this?

Comment: quite harsh since iterator have no length and your solution seems optimized...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to define your generator in a function so that it can be reused:

```
def spam_func():
    return (i for i in [1, 2, 3])

spam_length = sum(1 for _ in spam_func())
if spam_length <= max_size_for_foo:
    foo(spam_func())
else:
    bar(spam_func())
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as generator length, because generator easily can be infinite:

```
def square():
    a = 0
    while True:
        yield a**2
        a += 1
```

One solution is `sum(1 for _ in gen)`.
Another one may be wrap your generator with a class something like this:

```
class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def generate(self):
        yeild from self.items
```

Comment: How would `len(self.items)` work, if `self.items` is a generator and in particular without converting the entire generator to a list or similar (which I explicitly wanted to avoid)?

Comment: The point is that you create your own class instead of generator from an iterable object, like `list`. It is possible if the `spam` generator is not infinite and collection is known.

Comment: I understand that, but that does not handle the problem of generators having no `len`. If I am totally misunderstanding you, please demonstrate how I would actually use your `wrapper`.